# How to update future of future builder

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have a FutureBuilder and its future is getBusinessListByRating(), which makes a call to an API to get a BusinessList sorted by Rating. Then I press a button to sort the list alphabetically. When I do this, I want the future to be getBusinessListByAlpha() and to rerender.

How can I achieve this?

I tried using setState to update the future but it does not work.

Comment: thank you for joining the community. To be able to receive more help, could you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your state class you should initialize the future like this:

```
Future getBusinessListFuture;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getBusinessListFuture = getBusinessListByRating(rating);
}
```

and in your FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: getBusinessListFuture,
   builder: ....
)
```

to update future on button click:

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
     getBusinessListFuture = getBusinessListByRating(alphabetical);
  });
}
```

This should update the future and rebuild the widget.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a method that takes an argument instead, and just alter the argument. Then let that function call your specific secondary methods.

Something like:

```
enum BusinessListOrdering {
  rating,
  alpha,
  score
}

getBusinessListBy(BusinessListOrdering order) {
  switch (order) {
    case BusinessListOrdering.rating:
      return getBusinessListByRating();
    case BusinessListOrdering.alpha:
      return getBusinessListByAlpha();
    case BusinessListOrdering.score:    
      return getBusinessListByScore();
  default:
      return getBusinessListByRating();
  }
}
```

So when you press the button, you set the state for the enum variable in your widget.

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    order = BusinessListOrdering.alpha;
  });
},
```

and the FutureBuilder instead calls:

```
getBusinessListBy(order)
```